# Multiple content blocks

Tags: html, css

I cant get these two pieces of content to display next to each other. I never had any problems with displaying content this way before so would appreciate any help available

**HTML**

```
<div class="block-one">
<h3>Block 1</h3>
  <ol>
      <li><a href="#" title="">One</a></li>

  </ol>
</div>
<div class="clear-div"></div>

<div class="block-two">

 <div class="block-two-title">Block 2</div>
 <div class="thumb-title">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/example.jpg" width=155 height=130 /></a>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
</div>

<div class="thumb-title">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/example.jpg"width=155 height=130 /></a>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
</div>

<div class="thumb-title">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/example.jpg"width=155 height=130 /></a>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popular-games { float:left }

.latest-screenshots img{ display:inline-block}

.thumb-title{display: inline-block}`
```

Comment: Could you throw it up on a fiddle?

Comment: Or an screenshot on how do you see it? Also, the `html` tag definition will come in handy too.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález what is the problem?  There's a lot of stuff that's next to other stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/aMLQy/

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/htQtQ/

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to the block one will be next to the block two?

Comment: Don't know what you want to achieve. I see this: http://i.imgur.com/W253huv.png

Comment: Block two should be next to block one. As the question says

Comment: The question says: "Multiple content blocks".

Comment: Yes 2 is multiple, and content in block is next to each other

Comment: You're not applying any styles to block-one or block-two so why do you expect them to do anything but the default?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyX7N/). You cannot get those two blocks to display next to each other because you have a clearing div between them. If you remove it and float both blocks, you will get the desired result, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3rc7G/)

```
<div class="block-one">
<h3>Block 1</h3>
  <ol>
      <li><a href="#" title="">One</a></li>

  </ol>
</div>
<!-- remove this one <div class="clear-div"></div> -->

<div class="block-two">
[…]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these CSS rules:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

body > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Here is the Jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aMLQy/1/)